# How to overload json deserialization of float?

Tags: json, ruby, json-deserialization

I try to get how can I deserialize json like

```
 '{…, "money":{"amount":1.45674,"currency":"ETH"}, …}'
```

to my custom class or struct or whatever, using my own function. The goal is to convert the float to integer without rounding errors, and  I want to use my own money classes, depending of currency name. So there must not interfere BigDecimal or other numeric in the middle of conversion.

Or maybe the 1.45674 can be inside quotes, it's not a problem in that case.

Comment: Are you asking how to have a piece of JSON deserialized into an arbitrary class? Like you have a class called `Money::Ethereum` and you want the result of `JSON.parse` to include an instance of it in the case you mentioned?

Comment: Yes. Like that. And exactly what I want, that when parser see for example 'money:{…}' that piece of string will be parsed using my own converter.

Comment: Maybe Money::Ethereum.initialize(astring)

Comment: It would be helpful if you would provide a complete example, including the desired result. Please assign a variable to the JSON string (`json = '...'`) so that readers can refer to the variable without having to define it.

Comment: Did you considered to manipulate the data after the deserializantion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using [JSON from the Ruby standard library](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html), the following should make Ruby use your class:

- Add a `json_class` key to the JSON object with a value of your class name (for example, `'{"json_class":"Money::Ethereum","amount":1.45674}'`)
- Add a class method to your class called `json_create` that creates an object based on the JSON data (for example, `new(json_data['amount'])`)
- When you do the parsing, add a "create_additions" option: `JSON.parse(json_string, create_additions: true)`

You can see an example of this in the [JSON extension for `Range`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/json/rdoc/Range.html), which has a `json_create` class method, as well as `as_json` and `to_json` instance methods that output the value that can be fed back into `json_create`.

```
require 'json/add/range'
output = (0..10).to_json
JSON.parse(output, create_additions: true) # Returns the range 0..10
```